# Making a ladder in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help making a ladder.

Heres the info:

Tables:

```
cricket_teams(id, name)
cricket_matches(id, hometeam, awayteam, format, season, winner)
cricket_teamperformance(id, matchid, team, innings, score)
```

(there are other fields in the tables that are unnecessary for this query)

I need to get it so that it gives me the **wins**, draws (where winner = 0), losses, **FIP** (when a team scores more in the first innings), **BP** (in this case just winning) and **Points** (Ones in bold are done). I have a query but I have a few issues. I can't figure out how to get the draws and losses, and it also doesn't get teams who haven't won a game. Here's what I've got:

```
SELECT b.team, 
       b.name, 
       COUNT(c.wins) as W, 
       count(b.name)*2 as FIP, 
       COUNT(c.wins)*2 as BP, 
       COUNT(c.wins)*4+(count(b.name)*2)+(COUNT(c.wins)*2) as Pts
FROM (SELECT a.name, a.score, a.matchid, a.team
      FROM (SELECT cricket_teams.name, score, matchid, team
            FROM `cricket_teamperformance` 
            LEFT JOIN cricket_teams 
                   ON cricket_teamperformance.team = cricket_teams.id
            INNER JOIN cricket_matches 
                   ON cricket_teamperformance.matchid = cricket_matches.id
            WHERE cricket_matches.format=3
              AND cricket_teamperformance.innings = 1
              AND cricket_matches.season = 1
               OR cricket_matches.format=3
              AND cricket_teamperformance.innings = 2
              AND cricket_matches.season = 1
            ORDER BY matchid, score DESC) as a
      GROUP BY matchid) as b, 
     (SELECT COUNT(winner) as wins, cricket_teams.name
      FROM cricket_matches
      LEFT JOIN cricket_teams ON cricket_matches.winner = cricket_teams.id
      WHERE format = 3
      AND season = 1) as c
GROUP BY b.name
ORDER BY Pts DESC
```

And that returns this:

```
team    name    W   FIP BP  Pts
4   Chargers    2   4   4   16
2   Hawks       1   2   2   8
1   Ninjas      1   2   2   8
```

It needs to look like this (P is matches played, D is draws, L is losses):

```
team    name    P   W   D   L   FIP BP  Pts
4   Chargers    2   2   0   0   4   4   16
2   Hawks       2   1   0   1   2   2   8
1   Ninjas      2   1   0   1   2   2   8
3   Wolves      2   0   0   2   0   0   0
```

There is another team, Wolves, who have not won either of their two games. I also need to retrieve those draws and losses. Thanks in advance

*This is multiday cricket, meaning teams can have up to two innings per match.
SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26e41/2

Comment: Do yo have a SQL Fiddle for this?

Comment: No, never heard of it

Comment: Can you explain the logic for BP?

Comment: Bonus Points, in this case just winning outright, you just get an extra 2 points for winning along with the 4 for a win

Comment: Please check my latest answer and see if this is what you want.

Comment: It's not right. A team cannot have 2 wins and 2 losses and have only played 2 games. It needs to look like it does at the bottom of the question.

Comment: You didn't state the fact that in the Performance each team  plays 2 innings per match. Please add that information to the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution:

```
SELECT team,
       name,
       count(*)   AS p,
       sum(win)   AS w,
       sum(draw)  AS d,
       sum(loss)  AS l,
       sum(fi)*2  AS fip,
       sum(win)*2 AS bp,
       sum(win)*4 + sum(fi)*2 + sum(win)*2 AS pts
FROM
  (SELECT t.id AS team,
          t.name,
          m.winner = t.id AS win,
          m.winner = 0    AS draw,
          m.winner <> t.id AND m.winner <> 0 as loss,
          CASE
              WHEN p1.score > p2.score THEN p1.team = t.id
              ELSE p2.team = t.id
          END AS fi
   FROM cricket_matches m,
        cricket_teamperformance p1,
        cricket_teamperformance p2,
        cricket_teams t
   WHERE m.id = p1.matchid
     AND m.id = p2.matchid
     AND p1.innings = 1
     AND p2.innings = 2
     AND (t.id = m.hometeam
          OR t.id = m.awayteam)
     AND m.season = 1
     AND m.format = 3) tallies
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY pts DESC, name
```

Comment: That has done exactly what I wanted, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem description and tables schema very confusing, but maybe this will help you in some way:

```
SELECT  ct.id AS TeamID,
        ct.name AS TeamName,
        COUNT(DISTINCT cm.id) AS MatchesPlayed,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN cm.winner = ct.id THEN cm.id END) AS Wins,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN cm.winner = 0 THEN cm.id END) AS Draws,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN cm.winner != 0 AND cm.winner != ct.id THEN cm.id END) AS Losses,
        COUNT(DISTINCT
              CASE
                WHEN (ctph.innings = 1 OR ctpa.innings = 1) 
                      AND (ctph.team = ct.id AND ctph.score > ctpa.score)
                THEN ctph.matchid
                WHEN (ctph.innings = 1 OR ctpa.innings = 1) 
                      AND (ctpa.team = ct.id AND ctpa.score > ctph.score)
                THEN ctpa.matchid
              END) AS FIP
FROM    cricket_teams AS ct
        LEFT JOIN cricket_matches AS cm ON cm.hometeam = ct.id OR cm.awayteam = ct.id
        LEFT JOIN cricket_teamperformance AS ctph ON ctph.team = cm.hometeam AND ctph.matchid = cm.id
        LEFT JOIN cricket_teamperformance AS ctpa ON ctpa.team = cm.awayteam AND ctpa.matchid = cm.id
GROUP BY ct.id, ct.name
```

Comment: I just edited in that the format needs to be 3 and season needs to be 1. There's only one issue, that is the hawks have an extra FIP (which also needs to be multiplied by 2 but that's no biggie).